# More granular write_access

Tags: feature-request, api

With the new [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/), the [OAuth 2.0](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication) permissions system is pretty basic. There is `read_access`, and `write_access`.

This is pretty good for read-only apps or full-functionality apps (i.e. SE mobile apps), but this is a bit less useful for "tools" and other apps which may need a small subset of write access.

Especially as a mod, giving an app a key that lets it delete all the comments on the site is ... scary. It's inevitable, if I want to use something like a mobile app, but it prevents me from using other types of apps.

Could there be more granularity here? Maybe, in addition to `write_access` being a catch-all permission, add individual endpoint accesses?

Comment: I suspect this question is better suited to http://stackapps.com, the Q&A site for the API as well as for apps built around the API or the SE sites.

Comment: Yeah, this is technically better suited on Stack Apps, but it's also a very good point. It might also make sense to limit `write_access` to things a normal user can do, and then have a higher level of access for moderator-type requests.

Comment: @TimStone not sure how easy that would be to implement. IIRC the system backed doesn't really distinguish when it comes to comment deletions and whatnot (also, I tested the comment deletion endpoint before it went public, it could delete any comment)